# Splitting long object @return with anonymous type in JSDoc

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc, jsdoc3

When using an anonymous @return type with JSDoc the line can get very long.  How can these long lines be split?

E.g. starting with:

```
/**
* @return {{long_name: string, long_other_name: number, another_name: string, and_still_more: string}}
*/
myFunction: () => { ... }
```

This is is understood by VSCode (in that it can provide code completion for the members of the returned object), but is a long line

If I try:

```
/**
* @return {{long_name: string, long_other_name: number, 
* another_name: string, and_still_more: string}}
*/
myFunction: () => { ... }
```

VSCode marks the second line as an error and only understands the first line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper/canonical formatting of long JSDoc lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676286/what-is-the-proper-canonical-formatting-of-long-jsdoc-lines)

Comment: The linked question doesn't answer this question as VSCode doesn't parse the second line of a split @return statement

Comment: I think that might be your answer then.